# Random sampling from a population with mutually dependent elements

Tags: sampling, random-variable

After reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147038/40073) answer, I found myself confused. Say I am looking for the percentage of people who are likely to vote for a particular candidate. I am sampling from a population which is known to have groups with non-independent answers, for example, a family (such as husband and wife who gives exactly same answers). Hence, I can expect my sample to contain some of these groups too. Now, in a *strict* sense, can I use random sampling here to obtain the percentage of votes expected?

I understand sampling is routinely used, but is it usable in a strict theoretical sense? Or are we only taking about the independence of the sampling process alone, and not the population?

Comment: I edited the title to make it more informative. It could be made more elegant, but I am missing the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sample mean from a correlated sample is still unbiased, because of the linearity of expectation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity

The variance, however, could be much larger than if you have an uncorrelated sample (assuming positive correlation).

Comment: Any reference from basic stats books that I can read?

Comment: @linksys, could you expand your answer a little bit? One-liners are not very useful as answers (although could serve as comments).

Comment: @RichardHardy, I expanded my answer slightly.

Comment: @linksys, that's slightly better :)

Comment: About the variance, say we have a set of correlated random binary variables. Say I measure the output of each, and produce a set of black balls to represent Yes, and white balls to represent No in the measurement. Now, when I sample from this set of balls, shouldn't I get the same variance as that of the original correlated binary variables, even though the balls are not correlated?

Comment: @rahul, I'm not sure what you mean by "Say I measure the output of each and...". If the question is about whether you can produce a set of uncorrelated variables whose sample mean has the same variance as the sample mean from a set of variables with known correlation, the answer is yes.

Comment: @linksys, Let me explain what I mean; I have the 1,000 people voting, and after voting, we have 700 for, 300 against, and the population contains dependent elements as I explained in the question. From your answer, I understood that a sample of 100 from this population will have the same mean as that of a sample of 100 from a population containing 1000 independent elements, with 700 for, 300 against, however, with larger variation than the sample of 100 from the independent population. Is my understanding correct?